# Database of Android phones with out-of-the-box root access

Tags: data-request, computing, telecom

- Most Android phones can not be used as root without performing [special tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29).
- Others can be used as root immediately after purchase, without doing anything special.

Is there a database listing the latter?